# TFS Build queue issue

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have one build controller and it has 4 build agents in it. When I run more than one build at a time it queues the build. Why it doesn't run 4 builds parallel? Is there any settings that I should change?

- I am running TFS 2012.
- running gated checkin
- it also runs all the tests after the build is done.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: how long running are your builds? what type of builds are you running, build , unit test, integration tests? oh and what version of TFS?

Answer (score 0):

This is 'by design'. From [Use a gated check-in build process to validate changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd787631.aspx)

> Each gated check-in build definition can have only one running build at a time.

This is necessary to preserve the logic coherence of you version control.

If this is slowing your dev organization, you have many options (some are in the doc linked):

- Change from Gated to Batched gated
- Have multiple Build definitions (mapped on different portions of you sources)
- Minimize the checks during build
- Feed more resources to the Build server